# How to check if forked process has finished?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, system-calls, wait

I have a list of forked processes running in the backgrounds with their own pid, I want to check every x seconds every single job in the list and report if it's **finished** (done its job normally and not only stopped for some time) then remove it from the list.

```
void my_func()
{
    auto job = jobs.begin();
    while (job != jobs.end())
    {
        pid_t job_pid = job->pid;
        pid_t return_pid = waitpid(job_pid, nullptr, WNOHANG);
        if (return_pid == job_pid)
        {
            cout << "Finished" << endl;
            //remove from list
        } 
    }
}
```

Am I using waitpid correctly here?

---

**Some notes:**

- if the process was finished I won't ask again if it's finished or now since I am getting it out of my list.
- if the process is still active I may need to ask over and over again if it's finished or not.

Comment: Where do the `fork()` call takes place?

Comment: From what I recall your usage of `waitpid` will detect a 'status change' in the specified process -- not necessarily completion.  The [examples](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wait.3p.html#EXAMPLES) in the man page provide detailed usage more inline with what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

> ```
> pid_t return_pid = waitpid(job_pid, nullptr, WNOHANG);
> ```
>
> *Am I using waitpid correctly here?*

Yes.  If your aim is to sweep a list of child PIDs and non-blockingly check each to see whether any have terminated, this will do it.

Of course, the NULL status pointer means you won't be able to tell if the child exited normally or not, but you might not care.  It'd be wise, especially in production code, to check for errors like ECHILD, which might suggest that your application logic or data is corrupted (if, e.g., `job_pid` is nonsensical).  However, what you have might be good enough for your purposes.